# Rounded corners fail to cut off content in webkit browsers if position:relative

Tags: html, css, webkit, rounded-corners

Rounded corners fail to cut off content in webkit browsers (e.g. Chrome) if `position:relative;`

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eCsA3/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
<div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    background:yellow;
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:relative;/* Setting this means rounded corners don't cut off content! */
    overflow:hidden;

    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;   
}
.inner {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}
```

Anyone know of a fix?  Thanks-

Comment: It's working fine for me using FF4. What browser are you using? Also, you could try adding like a 2px padding to the div.

Comment: @Bryce- As I state in the question, this is an issue for Webkit (Chrome), not Gecko (FF4), browsers.

Comment: This is a bug in webkit. Can you file a ticket at http://bugs.webkit.com ?

Comment: Correcting Paul's link..it's http://bugs.webkit.org , you can file a ticket here

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=54189

Comment: @Yarin I just earned the necromancer for my answer on this question. Perhaps its time to accept?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
span.outer{
    position:relative;
}

div.outer {
    background:yellow;
    border:solid 1px black;    
    overflow:hidden;    
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;   
}

.inner {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

Original JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/USd5s/

Hate to add extra dom elements but a simple wrapper fixes this right up. You don't have to use my choice of element or css method either, span and qualified css is just my taste. <div class="wrap> or something would work just as well.

Comment: This works, however as indicated this is merely a hack for a webkit bug. Further testing shows that while performing CSS transitions on the elements beneath, this technique will fail. Only after the transition completes does the overflow:hidden work properly again.

Comment: @Joshua can you put that in a fiddle for me?

Answer (score 8):

You can force it to render in 3d with:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);   
-moz-transform: translateZ(0);   
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the inner to the same border radius as the outer.

```
.inner {
    -moz-border-radius: inherit;
    -webkit-border-radius: inherit;
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

Oh, and don't forget the webkit peoples. :]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in a project and solve it with a little change in the CSS

instead of setting **position** to **relative** I set it to **inherit**:

```
.outer {
    background:yellow;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: inherit;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius: 12px;   
}
```

And that solved perfectly the problem.

Comment: Not a solution- inherit will just use whatever position the parent element has

Answer (score 0):

You can give the inner div the same border-radius: http://jsfiddle.net/eCsA3/8/

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
<div>

<style type="text/css">
.outer {
    background:yellow;
    border:solid 1px black;
    position:relative;/* Setting this means rounded corners don't cut off content! */
    overflow:hidden;

    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;   
}
.inner {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;   
}
</style>
```

Comment: @Flauwekeul- This would work in this simple example but does not solve the problem for when the outer div would have more complex content that did not necessarily sit flush at the corners.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I read somewhere that you have to clip the container to something in order to solve this problem. I'm not really sure, but I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

As Paul Said, Bug in webkit, But you can still get around it using margins on inner div.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as the CSS for `.inner`:

```
.inner {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    bottom: 1px;
}
```

You will need to tweak `bottom` and `top` to get the height right. If left unchanged, the class will only have a height of one pixel. This method will set the left and right margins to the border radius, so nothing appears on the edges.

Alternatively, if you have a solid color background around `.outer` you could make an image like this: [image: Rounded Corner PNG]
where the area inside (the checkered area in the image) is transparent and the area outside is the background color. Then use border image or absolute positioning to place it where the corners are. Give it a high `z-index`. When you scroll, the contents will be hidden underneath the filled part of the corner.

Comment: I put your solution in [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCsA3/113/) and it does not work at all.  In Safari, it collapses the entire div into a horizontal line.

Comment: That's why you should add `bottom` as a property (as I said). I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DZTvR/). This solves your problem.

```css
#wrapper {
    margin-top:250px;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute; /* this breaks the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
}
```