# Possible or Misused Feature? Overflow:Hidden Weirdness

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

Here is very interesting case.

When overflow:hidden is used with position:relative, weird things start to happen. See for yourselves!

http://cssdeck.com/labs/u1om11qq

**HTML**

```
<div class="carrier">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.carrier{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:200px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background:blue;
}
.button {
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease;
    transition:all 0.2s ease;
}
.button:hover{
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

Is this situation (blinking edges) a bug, or am I missing a point?

(Overflow:hidden needs to cover the edges -- it creates a weird blinking on chrome 24.0.1312.57.m)

Comment: What's wrong ? What shall we see ? What 'weird' things ??

Comment: Just edited the question-

Comment: search for border-radius bug chrome

Comment: I'm on the same version of chrome and I dont see any blinking. The corners do seem to get 'stuck' halfway through the fade out when the mouse leaves though. Very odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in webkit for this.

You can check it out here :

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67950

> Description From Niklas 2011-09-12 13:04:56 PST When using
>   border-radius on parent element (with overflow:hidden) the child nodes
>   are clipped according to the radius. However, is any -webkit-transform
>   property is used on the parent or the child nodes the border-radius is
>   lost.
>
> Example available here: http://jsfiddle.net/DkXuR/

In this case it seems that it breaks with `-webkit-transition` too!

Wrap your target element in `wrapper` element and transform it!

There are plenty of bugs regarding rounded corners and clipping the content with `overflow:hidden` :

- [Rounded corners fail to cut off content in webkit browsers if position:relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144398/rounded-corners-fail-to-cut-off-content-in-webkit-browsers-if-positionrelative)
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68196