# border-radius not respected after google map rendering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

Strange problem here, help apreciated.

I have a page populated with houses for renting and a Google map.
All houses info and images are generated by php/SQL so the `<li>` and `<div>`structure is the same.

I croped the thumb of each house by hiding it in a div with `overflow:hidden`. I put also `border-radius` on that div. All works good for 1 second until google maps has loaded.

**The problem is** that after google map has loaded, some pictures ignore the border-radius CSS setting and the visible part of those images/thumb "jump out" - (but not the hidden part of the image) . I see the border disappearing behind the corners but the image doesn't respect the border-radius anymore.

**EDIT_1**: this is only happening in Chrome.

**ANSWER**: It seems to be a webkit but. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144398/rounded-corners-fail-to-cut-off-content-in-webkit-browsers-if-positionrelative). 
"Removing the `position:absolute` declaration from the img elements seems to resolve this issue" - Thank you @Boaz

What is happening here? any better way to do this?
Thanks

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPZRj.jpg)

[Zoomed detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH56x.jpg)

Comment: Can you see that the elements still have the CSS applied to them?

Comment: Hi @Ian, yes they do. I see the border of the div intact with the radius, and also on the Developer tools

Comment: Debugging without a live link or code is a gueseing game

Comment: post up a fiddle or something this would be impossible for anyone to figure just on images

Comment: @davidstrachan, just edited and added live llink. thank you

Comment: @Sergio Works OK for me in Crome

Comment: @davidstrachan, interesting and strage. I have two pc at home with same problem on Chrome, same Chrome ver. but  different windows os. Same problem on mobile/chrome

Comment: Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m Windows Vista Have you tried clearing caches?

Comment: Yes, tried it and no change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transparent rounded corners on Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894439/transparent-rounded-corners-on-google-map)

Comment: Removing the `position:absolute` declaration from the `img` elements seems to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for help. It's a Chrome bug.

"*Removing the `position:absolute` declaration from the img elements seems to resolve this issue.* "– Boaz

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894439/transparent-rounded-corners-on-google-map)